# App as a remote controller

Tags: android

I'm looking for an app to android cellphone. It is a remote controller that you can go forward or backward when you have a presention with your computer using PowerPoint. Do you know any app?

Answer (score 1):

I use [**Unified Remote Controller**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Relmtech.Remote). It contains remotes for many computer applications, including PowerPoint, with two remotes for either basic or advanced controls. Features are:

- Can control a wide array of apps, including PowerPoint
- Buttons for going backwards and forwards in a presentation
- Ability to create a custom homescreen widget with the buttons of your choice

It has a free version, but the PowerPoint remote is only available in the full version

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PowerPoint controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ppt&hl=en):

- gratis
- can go forward or backward when you have a presentation with your computer (Microsoft Windows) using PowerPoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PowerPoint Remote Presenter](http://www.android-powerpoint.com/powerpoint/):

- gratis (but premium version available)
- can go forward or backward when you have a presentation with your computer (Microsoft Windows) using PowerPoint.
- also supports OpenOffice

Answer (score 0):

One more app which you can customize however you like is Matricapp - check out [example powerpoint deck](https://community.matricapp.com/deck/81/powerpoint-remote).

- gratis for up to 6 buttons
- customize to your needs
- uses Wi-Fi to connect (bluetooth to be added)